# How can my SourceGenerator project reference my .NET 6 ClassLibrary project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a Class Library project that use .NET6. My Source Generator that is used by a third project is, as required, .NET Standard 2.0.

My Source Generator need to reference classes defined in the Class Library. However, Visual Studio tells me

> Project '..\Enigma.Game\Enigma.Game.csproj' targets 'net6.0'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'.

In which Enigma.Game.csproj is the Class Library referenced by the Source Generator.

Answer (score 0):

You can only reference a project with a lower runtime version than what you use. In this case, the Source Generator uses .NETStandard 2.0, hence it can only reference assemblies that also target .NETStandard 2.0 (or older). You need to build your `Enigma.Game.csproj` with .NETStandard 2.0 (either exclusively or in addition to .NET 6.0).